# Convert 1,2 string to array [1, 2]

Tags: arrays, string, grails

i think it is a simple problem but it took me some times to convert `1,2` to array `[1, 2]` using grails. Can you help me to convert `1,2` to array `[1, 2]`

Comment: "Can you help me to convert 1,2 to array [1, 2]" - Is the original `1,2` a `String`?

Comment: Which of course also begs the question: do you do some toString somewhere along your steps which messes things up?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need something specific to grails (or groovy, rather)...  simple java `String.split()` should suffice.

```
String s = "1,2"
String[] array = s.split(",")
```

or if you really just want to be groooooovy

```
def array = "1,2".split(",")
```